# Is it possible Create and Close wcf Service Host in MS Test

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, mstest

I usually use NUnit as a UnitTest Framework ,however where I work now they use solely MSTest .
In Nunit I could use the following:

```
    [FixtureSetup]
    public override void MainSetup()
    {
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService));
        _serviceHost.Open();
     }
     [FixtureTearDown]
     public override void MainTeardown()
     {
        _serviceHost.Close();
     }
```

I have noticed that in MSTest if you want to initialize for the duration of all test and close after all tests have run you have to use below STATIC method and as you know I cannot use my class anymore.
The below method will crash!!!

```
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService));
        _serviceHost.Open();
    }
```

How can I initialize my service Host once and close after all the test have run in MSTest?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by 'crash'? Could you be more specific what problem you encounter? Is it a compiler error, a stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `_serviceHost` variable static too, you should be safe.

Comment: Apology for late reply.Just now managed to get online.That worked.Why didnt I think of that. THANKS!!